# Visual tab bug on Microsoft Edge

Tags: bug, new-nav, microsoft-edge

Moving your mouse on a tab gave me a weird feeling on [Microsoft Edge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Edge).

I was seeing things:

[image]

[image]

Expand keep flashing every time my mouse moves across the tab.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Use Edge
2. Login
3. Move the mouse

This make the all thing literally unusable!

Comment: Workaround: Stop using edge

Comment: Do not burinate me with the [microsoft-edge]  tag that is actually a duplicate of [bug]

Comment: Looks like this doesn't have to do with the top-bar, but rather the new-nav. Because the circles are around the tab area, not the top-bar (which is the logo, Questions, Jobs, etc. area). I have Edge and the top-bar is working fine.

Comment: So, there is a chevron beside each tab. The chevron is actually an element which contains the text "expand" which is hidden and turned into a chevron with CSS. It looks like there is an issue with that CSS.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this on Edge 38.14393.0.0.

Comment: @TinyGiant: To be picky, that's not a chevron ;)

Comment: Repro'd here, also on 14393.